# How does a keyboard shortcut function?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

For example (using Mac OSX), when I have the Notes application open and hit `CMD + N` a new note will be created. But this is what the user interprets it as. What code is being executed when these two buttons are pushed?

Comment: Why is this tagged as python? The code being executed would be compiled code in the Notes application.

Comment: @nbryans I made an edit that should fix it if approved. :)

Comment: Unintentionally tagged as python. Removed.

Comment: I'm a beginner to coding and stackoverflow so your help is very appreciated with that edit @bjskistad

Comment: No problem! Just helping out! :D

Comment: I think it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012566/swift-osx-key-event